# Replacing values between chars with spaces in java

Tags: java, regex

I have an XML like this,

```
<order_details>
   <order_count>#ordercount#</order_count>
   <value_date>#valuedate#</value_date>
   <report_date>2012-04-25</report_date>
   <from_facility>#fromfacility#</from_facility>
</order_details>
```

I would like to replace all values which are starting and ending with # by space.

The output of the above XML should be,

```
<order_details>
   <order_count></order_count>
   <value_date></value_date>
   <report_date>2012-04-25</report_date>
   <from_facility></from_facility>
</order_details>
```

I tried to use `string.replaceAll("<*>#.*#</*>", "")` but it doesn't work.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Show us what you get instead of just saying it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
string.replaceAll(">#.*?#</", "></")
```

By default, quantifiers `*`, `+`, `?`, `{n}`, `{n,}`,  `{n,m}` are *greedy*, i.e. it will try the longest possible string that matches the sub-pattern that is being repeated. Adding `?` after a quantifier, using the regex above as an example: `.*?`, will make it *lazy*, i.e. it will try the shortest possible string that matches the sub-pattern that is being repeated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `string.replaceAll("#.*?#", "")`

Comment: What does it return? The above one works on my machine. Don't forget the question mark.

Comment: My mistake. Instead of checking the output, outputString = string.replaceAll("#.*?#", ""), I was checking the xml string itself. Both solutions, string.replaceAll("#.*?#", "") and string.replaceAll(">#.*?#</", "></") are working fine. Thanks a lot.